# Reading from a text file and then Write to the text file in same classic ASP script

Tags: asp-classic

```
<%
    dim narrationCounter,logDateString,logDate,      logTime,folderName,folderPath,logFolder2,month,day,year,txtFilePath


    logDateString = Request.Form("logDateString")
    logDate = Date()
    folderName = "NarrationClickLog" & "_" & logDate
    month = DatePart("m",Now())
    day = DatePart("d", Now())
    year = DatePart("yyyy",Now())


    folderPath = "D:\iisroot\casecomments\CaseNarrationClickLog" + "_" & month & "_" & day & "_" & year
    txtFilePath = folderPath + "\CaseNarrationClickLog.txt"

    visitorIP=Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
    visitorUserName = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_USER")
    visitorHost = Request.ServerVariables("remote_host")

    set oFs = server.createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If  Not oFs.FolderExists(folderPath) Then      


        set logFolder=oFs.CreateFolder(folderPath)

    End If

    ' Extract last updated narration button click value from text file

    if oFs.FileExists(txtFilePath) then
                if oFs.GetFile(txtFilePath).size <> 0 then  'Get narrationCounterVal from log file
                  ' open the file and Read it
                    set oTextFile = oFs.OpenTextFile(txtFilePath, 1 , true) 'forreading
                    ReadMe = oTextFile.ReadAll
                    Tab = split(ReadMe,vbcrlf)

                    i = ubound(Tab) - 2
                    paragraph=paragraph & Tab(i) & ""
                    Response.Write("Paragraph is : " + paragraph)

                    paragraphReverse = StrReverse(paragraph)
                    Response.Write( paragraphReverse )

                    ' get the narration counter
                    narrationCounterPos = Split(paragraphReverse) 
                    'Default delimiter is the space character..in this case Split at the Space before colon SO first element in array is narration counter number 
                    narrationCounterVal = StrReverse(narrationCounterPos(0))
                    'Response.Write("Latest Narration Counter from text file is :-  " + narrationCounterVal)

                    narrationCounter = narrationCounterVal +  1

                    oTextFile.Close
                    set oTextFile = nothing

                    WriteToLogFile(narrationCounter)    

                else  ' Set narration Counter Value  = 1 , A NEW FIRST Record entry.

                                narrationCounter = 1
                                WriteToLogFile(narrationCounter)

                end if

                Response.Write("Latest Narration Counter value :-  " + narrationCounterVal)

                Response.Write("file exists")

    else

        Response.Write("File does not exist")
    end if

    function WriteToLogFile(narrationCounter)

                set oTextFileWrite = oFs.OpenTextFile(txtFilePath, 8, True)   '  "D:\IISROOT\CaseComments\CaseNarrationClickLog.txt"

                oTextFileWrite.WriteLine " User IP Address: " + visitorIP  +  " User Name: " + visitorUserName + "  Clicks on DATE : " +  logDateString + " are : " + narrationCounter

                Response.Write("Text file path : -" + txtFilePath & " visitor IP :  " & visitorIP & " User name: " & visitorUserName & " visitor host: " & visitorHost)

                oTextFileWrite.Close
                set oTextFileWrite = nothing


    end function

    oTextFile.Close
    set oTextFile = nothing
    oTextFileWrite.Close
    set oTextFileWrite = nothing
    set oFS = nothing


    %>
```

This code must do the following:

1. Checks if folder exists, if not, create
2. Check if text file exists, If Yes then Read contents from text file in the above way, extract the narrationCounterVal variable value and then WRITE to the text file using the WritetoLogFile(narrationCounter) function

Problem: Just stuck. The folder and file get created BUT nothing gets written to it. I am also making sure that I close the oTextFile object used for opening file in Read mode before I call the Writetologfile function.

Comment: Is this the whole page ? Do you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere ?If you do, comment it out temporarily.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ or even forever, if you are using `On Error Resume Next` it should never be set globally but instead used sparingly to test a statement for an error then switched off again using `On Error Goto 0`.